# Get an image dimensions using Javascript and applying it to any other element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried this  but it's not working, how could I get this working, to #sky2 get the same height & width of #sky? I may change #sky2 to div or whatever.

```js
function ImgWH() {
  var mImg = document.querySelector("#sky");
  var mWidth = mImg.clientWidth;
  var mHeight = mImg.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("sky2").style.width = mWidth;
}
```

```css
#sky {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky2">
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you must invoke your function, but then when it runs, you must remember to add a unit of measurement onto the value you are setting, otherwise it is not know how wide to make the element.

```js
function ImgWH() {
  var mImg = document.getElementById("sky");
  var mWidth = mImg.clientWidth;
  var mHeight = mImg.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("sky2").style.width = mWidth + "px"; // <-- must add unit
}

ImgWH();  // <-- Remember to invoke your function
```

```css
#sky {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the width from first image and set it to width from second image (note the 'px' is necessary) and don't forget to start the function.

```js
function ImgWH() {
    var myImg = document.getElementById("sky");
    var myImg2 = document.getElementById("sky2");
    var mWidth = myImg.width;
    var mHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
    myImg2.style.width = mWidth +'px';
}

ImgWH();
```

```css
#sky {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" id="sky2">
```

Comment: The `setTimeout()` is not necessary.

Comment: I tried it without but the second picture was not resized.

Comment: If you look at my answer, you'll see that it works.

Comment: You are right, but removing the setTimeout() doesn't help allone. I had to remove the onload-functions from the images and than it works as desired. Suprisingly I thought by  onload is ensured that the image is present and otherwise it could be to early. Definitely it should not have such an effect. I corrected it.